# Process.Start in BackgroundWorker C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, waitforexit

I'm having the worst time wrapping my head around threads/background processes.  My issues seem common enough to a certain point but I've yet to find a good example that meets my needs.

The classic example goes like this:
My UI freezes when a certain long running task/process runs -I want to be able to at least move/minimize the UI.

Classic replies include Threading and Task Factories and BackgroundWorker solutions.
but no matter how I implement them I get poor results.

In my program, I'm executing another application and waiting for it to finish. For the sake of simplicity let's say I'm doing it like so:

```
            Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe somefile.txt");
            p.WaitForExit();
            //read somefile.txt
```

Clearly my application UI would hang while `WaitForExit()` grinds away waiting for me to close notepad.

I've attempted a number of suggested means around this but I get painted into one of two corners:

1. My interface still hangs, then reads somefile.txt just fine when I close notepad.
2. The Process (Notepad) runs fine but my application reads somefile.txt immediately before I have closed notepad (So I guess it's running asynchronously)

Most examples I see involve counting to a high number -simple but not quite what I'm doing.  Firing off this "external" process complicates things a bit.

Thanks for your time and consideration!!

Comment: If you are doing this on background thread then your UI won't hang since you are waiting on other thread and not UI thread.

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code, show a minimal program that will start notepad, using a backgroundworker, and still hangs.

Comment: Have you tried using a *BackgroundWorker* and reading somefile.txt in the worker's *AfterCompleted* handler?

Comment: Rohit you're correct the UI doesn't hang but it the application keeps running as if "somefile.txt" was edited.  I need to be able to interact with the UI (move it out of the way) while the background process runs but not "continue" until process is complete.  Sorry if that's vaugue

Comment: You should consider to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx (to handle events when file is changed) instead of using WaitForExit.

Comment: Lasse I would like to but, it's doing a lot more than that (Notepad is just a simple example).  I'm not sure how to post without confusing the core issue.  BackgroundWorker is just one method I tried.

Comment: retailcoder: I don't see a "AfterCompleted" handler

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` has event `RunWorkerCompleted` which gets called on UI thread once your `DoWork` handler is done with background processing. Have you tried using that?

Comment: @FredB right that was off memory... see `RunWorkderCompleted` event.

Comment: Retail:When I used RunWorkderCompleted it read the file just fine.. but I was painted into "corner 2" again. Ghaa... I wish I could explain better.. I call a method with the background worker... pass something like "someFileToOpen".  BackGroundWorker ran fine but the code after that call keeps running as well... I need to UI to wait for the background to complete but not hang.

Comment: outcoldman:  Thanks but I'm just using notepad as an example.  Not actually editing a file.  I'm running an application that performs a long running task.

Comment: If your problem is "wrapping my head around threads", then read the introduction to [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading) by Joseph Albahari. 

I can't answer your actual problem because you have not explained in enough detail for me to understand what you are doing; if you are simply "waiting for it to finish" then `delegate.BeginInvoke()` will do that in a single line of code. But then you say you're "doing a lot more than that". We need to know exactly what you are trying to do; oversimpified examples that do not show what you are trying to do confuses more than helps.

Comment: Dour: Yeah I'm getting that the example leaves a lot to be desired.  It's difficult to find a happy medium in the example.  I think I leaned towards "over simple" hoping that would yield a simple solution.  I'll check out your link

Answer (score 1):

BackgroundWorker seems appropriate here; it should be configured something along those lines:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then you have the handlers:

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //start notepad process here.
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //read somefile.txt here.
}
```

Comment: So, How do I (for example) pass the file name to the worker_DoWork method _I'm really showing my inexperience here.

Comment: I think you'll still want the `p.WaitForExit()` in the `worker_DoWork` handler.

Comment: Also... lets say I had code after the worker.RunWorkerAsync(); that did something with the content of the text file.. In my code it just keeps right on going there even though it's not been updated

Comment: You'll want to put that in the `RunWorkderCompleted` handler (just noticed the typos in the code.. sorry about that)

Comment: I did have the waitForexit in DoWork but that hung the UI

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of things your application isn't running the `Process.WaitForExit` call on a separate thread otherwise there wouldn't be any hanging.

`BackgroundWorker`, `Thread` and the `ThreadPool` are all useful tools, but they can be difficult and cumbersome to work with and get right, the Task Parallel Library with `System.Threading.Task` has somewhat "superseded" using threads directly for most operations you need to perform asynchronously.

See: [Threads and the new Task library in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418979/threads-and-the-new-task-library-in-c-sharp)

So your code becomes.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   var proc = new Process("...");
   proc.WaitForExit();
   File.Read("...");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Clint let me see if I can try this.  In the case, could File.Read be placed outside the Task Factory code? -my example is quite simplified.

Comment: So.. This painted me into corner 2.  My process ran great but The code after This task factory ran immediately.  Sorry If I'm being vague.  BTW I think you're missing a ); on the last line.

Comment: The `System.Threading.Task` namespace is amazing - for the record it should be noted that it's not available in earlier versions of the .net framework (appeared in 4.0 I think).

Comment: Running 4.  This seems like a dead simple way to go but the task go off by itself and my application goes some other direction

Comment: @FredB that's the point of multithreading and asynchrony no? To be able to run something at the same time as something else? If you want to wait for the task to finish you can use the `.Wait` method, but then you'll get the main thread hanging again and defeat the purpose of using a background thread...

Comment: @FredB and you are indeed correct, I was missing the close parentheses and semicolon... oops.